# Give new members a role based on the invite code used d.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to give users who joined using the disboard invite a 'no-invite' role, because my server gets raided very often. Someone joins trough db, then invites 20 others etc..

This is the code I use:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from variables import no_invite_role_id, disboard_invite, logs_channel_id

invites = {}


def find_invite_by_code(invite_list, code):
    for inv in invite_list:
        if inv.code == code:

            return inv


class Disboard(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            invites[guild.id] = await guild.invites()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):

        invites_before_join = invites[member.guild.id]

        no_invite_role = member.guild.get_role(no_invite_role_id)

        logs_channel = self.bot.get_channel(logs_channel_id)

        invites_after_join = await member.guild.invites()

        for invite in invites_before_join:

            if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:

                await logs_channel.send(f"{member.mention}, `{member.id}` a intrat prin disboard")

                if disboard_invite in invite.code:
                    await member.add_roles(no_invite_role, reason="A intrat prin disboard")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1200)
                    try:
                        await member.remove_roles(no_invite_role, reason="Perioada no-invite a expirat")
                    except:
                        await logs_channel.send(f"{member} a iesit inainte de expirarea perioadei no-invite")

                invites[member.guild.id] = invites_after_join

                return


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Disboard(bot))
```

For some reason, this code sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. 70% of the time it works on my pc, but only 10% on my host.
This is the error that i get when it's not working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/discord/client.py", line 351, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/disboard.py", line 38, in on_member_join
    if invite.uses < find_invite_by_code(invites_after_join, invite.code).uses:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'uses'
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
```

*I also have on_ready in another cog, but I don't think that does anything.

Comment: Could it be memory getting full? with `invites`

Comment: May be..the code is not optimized at all. I used the only python invite tracking code I could find.. But I have less than 30 invites on my server and the bot uses 50-60 mb of ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, thanks to https://github.com/GregTCLTK/Discord-Invite-Tracker

```
# Original code: GregTCLTK 2018-2021.
# Contact Developer on https://discord.gg/nPwjaJk (Skidder#8515 | 401817301919465482)
# Original repo: https://github.com/GregTCLTK/Discord-Invite-Tracker
# Original cog by: Quill (quillfires)
# Edited by Mihai Cristian

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed
import asyncio

disboard_invite = "xxxxx"
no_invite_role_id = 0000000000

class invite_tracker(commands.Cog):
    """
    Keep track of your invites
    """
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.version = "1.0.0"

        self.invites = {}
        bot.loop.create_task(self.load())

    async def load(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        # load the invites
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            try:
                self.invites[guild.id] = await guild.invites()
            except:
                pass

    def find_invite_by_code(self, inv_list, code):
        for inv in inv_list:
            if inv.code == code:
                return inv

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        no_invite_role = member.guild.get_role(no_invite_role_id)
        try:
            invs_before = self.invites[member.guild.id]
            invs_after = await member.guild.invites()
            self.invites[member.guild.id] = invs_after
            for invite in invs_before:
                if invite.uses < self.find_invite_by_code(invs_after, invite.code).uses:
                    if disboard_invite in invite.code:
                        try:
                            await member.add_roles(no_invite_role, reason="Joined through disboard")
                            await asyncio.sleep(1200)
                            try:
                                await member.remove_roles(no_invite_role, reason="The no-invite period has expired")
                            except:
                                pass
                        except:
                            pass


        except:
            pass

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        try:
            self.invites[guild.id] = await guild.invites()
        except:
            pass

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
        try:
            self.invites.pop(guild.id)
        except:
            pass


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(invite_tracker(bot))
```